# Attempting to identify non-integer values using for loop

Tags: stata

I am trying to identify values that are not integers in Stata. My dataset is the following:

```
var1  var2  var3
1     2     3
2     4     5
3     6     7
4     2     3 
5     1     1
6     2     8
```

My code is the following:

```
foreach var in var1 var2 var3 {
   gen flag_`var' = 1 if format(`var') == %int
   replace flag_`var' = 0 if flag_`var' ==.
```

I am getting an error message stating

```
unknown function format()
}
```

I also tried replacing the parentheses around `` format(`var') `` with `` format[`var'] `` but then I got an error stating format not found. Is there something wrong with the format I am using or is there a better way to identify non-integer values?

Comment: Please reply to the answer to your previous question by @dimitriy  by either accepting the answer or explaining why it is not what you seek.

Answer (score 3):

The first answer is what Stata told you: there is no `format()` function.

But a deeper answer is that thinking of (display) formats is the wrong way round for this question. A display format is in essence an **instruction** to show data in a certain way and has nothing to do with its stored value, or to be more precise the decimal equivalent of its stored value. Thus 42 displayed with format `%4.3f` is shown as 42.000 while 6.789 displayed with format `%1.0f` is shown as 7. Otherwise put, no value has an inherent format, but a display format is used to display a value, either by default or because a user specified a format. Stata is here just using the same broad ideas as say C and various C-like languages.

*Nothing to do with its stored value* is a slight exaggeration, as only numeric formats make sense for numbers and only string formats make sense for strings, but display format has nothing to do with whether a stored value is integer.

Further `%int` is not a display format any way. When formats are being checked for, they would be literal strings enclosed in `""`.

To show non-integers various methods could be used, say using rounding functions such as `round()`, `int()`, `floor()` or `ceil()`. So an indicator for whether `x` is integer could be

```
 gen is_int_x = x == floor(x)
```

All the values in your data example are integer any way, but I take it that you are looking for non-integers elsewhere.